# Elements of Programming Interviews - Look And Say

Tags: python, algorithm

Going through `Elements of Programming Interviews` and looking at the following problem:

> Find the n’th term in Look-and-say (Or Count and Say) Sequence. The look-and-say sequence is the sequence of below integers:
>   1, 11, 21, 1211, 111221, 312211, 13112221, 1113213211, …

The author's solution is below:

```
def look_and_say(n):
  def next_number(s):
    result, i = [], 0 
    while i < len(s):
      count = 1 
      while i + 1 < len(s) and s[i] == s[i + 1]:
        i += 1 
        count += 1
      result.append(str(count) + s[i])
      i += 1 
    return ''.join(result)

  s = '1'
  for _ in range(1, n):
     s = next_number(s)
  return s
```

Here's my question: the recursive call, which happens `O(2^N)` times, generates both an array and a string. I understand that that is just a constant factor extra in space cost, but wouldn't it be more efficient to use the recursive function build a list, and then instead of `return s`, return `''.join(s)`?

Comment: This code doesn't seem to be valid - what's in the for loop? What calls the inner function?

Comment: EPI has its own forum, authors respond there: http://talk.elementsofprogramminginterviews.com/

Comment: For ayone who hasn't heard of the look-and-say sequence: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks - left out the line that calls the inner function :( apologies

Comment: It's a fun challenge to do this with only math (i.e. no strings).